# moving objects between view controllers

Tags: ios, segue

I am new in programming and I have problem with moving objects from one VC to another.

My second VC have `NSArray * objects`. Third VC have `NSMutableArray` *products. I have modal segue from 2 -> 3
Here is my segue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Products segue"]) {
     ProductsViewController*pvc = segue.destinationViewController;
     pvc.products = [self.objects mutableCopy];
}
```

}

In `ProductsViewController` i create few objects:

```
-(IBAction)addSomeObjects {
products = [NSMutableArray new];
[products addObject:@"Cola"];
[products addObject:@"Pepsi"];
[products addObject:@"Fanta"];
[products addObject:@"Red bull"];
[products addObject:@"Monster"];
```

If I NSLog my `IBAction` method products successfully added my objects but when I `dissmissViewController` my objects array is empty.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This: `pvc.products = [self.objects mutableCopy]` creates a new mutable array that contains the same objects as `self.objects`.  This: `products = [NSMutableArray new]` creates a new empty array.  There is nothing in what you've shown that would change `self.objects`.

Comment: So what should i do to change my self.objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M.
Koptak. Welcome to programming.

In this example, I would suggest you create a model to manage products. A model is a class that represents data. In this example, create a class to represent the collection of products. For this I will call it a catalog.

```
// In Catalog.h
@interface Catalog : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray *products;
@end

// In Catalog.m
@implementation Catalog
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _products = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
@end
```

Now that I have a class which can manage products, I need to have `catalog` properties (of type `Catalog`) in both the first view controller and `ProductsViewController`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Products segue"]) {
        ProductsViewController *pvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        pvc.catalog = self.catalog; // Pass the catalog between the view controllers.
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    …
    if (self.catalog == nil) // Make sure an instance of `Catalog` has been created!
        self.catalog = [[Catalog alloc] init];
    …
}
```

Finally, in `ProductsViewController`

```
-  (IBAction)addSomeObjects
{
    [self.catalog.products addObject:@"Cola"];
    [self.catalog.products addObject:@"Pepsi"];
    [self.catalog.products addObject:@"Fanta"];
    [self.catalog.products addObject:@"Red bull"];
    [self.catalog.products addObject:@"Monster"];
}
```

Now when you dismiss `ProductsViewController`, the first view controller will have all the new products.

Note: This is the very first step in how to share data. It skips proper class names, data protection, and data validation, but it gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for show me better solution. It works fine, but i need that objects in my NSArray :)  It work with my search bar so i need fill it with that objects to show that objects in my search bar table view.

Comment: Oh i got it. In viewWillAppear i've put self.objects = self.catalog.products;  Now it works finally ! :) many thanks to you